# Encoding and decoding enum of type TimeInterval

Tags: swift, codable

Given is the following enum:

```swift
    enum TimerType: TimeInterval, Codable {

        case timer, `break`

        var rawValue: TimeInterval {
            switch self {
            case .timer: return 60 * 25
            case .break: return 60 * 5
            }
        }

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case timer = "timer"
            case `break` = "break"
        }
    }
```

I want save its values in structs that are using this enum to json like this:

```
{
  "type": "timer"
}
```

But what it actually does is

```
{
  "type": 1500
}
```

While I can see that it actually saves the `Double` value (as it's of type `TimerInterval` which is a typealias of Double), I cannot figure out how to encode and decode with their names.
Any hints?

Comment: An enum with `Double` raw value cannot en-/decode a `String`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense actually – thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the timing values hardcoded, I would suggest switching to a String-based enum:

```
enum TimerType: String, Codable {

    case timer, `break`

    var timerValue: TimeInterval {
        switch self {
        case .timer: return 60 * 25
        case .break: return 60 * 5
        }
    }
}
```